# Getting the Correct Iterator

Tags: scala, anonymous

The intention behind the first snippet of code below is to define a new trait for iterables that provides an additional method for prepending a new element in front of the iterable.

However, when running the code in the second snippet, we see that the `+:` method returns an iterable yielding an infinity of `0`s.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the intended behavior?

Note: I added the `outer` val to make sure I get the correct iterator when defining the methods of the object returned by `+:`; I don't know how to get access to that iterator otherwise (`Iterable2.this.iterator` did not compile).

```scala
trait Iterable2[A] extends Iterable[A] {
  val outer :Iterable[A] = this
  def +:(elem :A) = new Iterable2[A] {
    override def iterator: Iterator[A] = new Iterator[A] {
      private[this] var virgin = true
      override def hasNext: Boolean = virgin || outer.iterator.hasNext
      override def next(): A = {
        if (virgin) {virgin = false; elem}
        else outer.iterator.next()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```scala
val i = new Iterable2[Int] {
  override def iterator: Iterator[Int] = Iterator(1,2,3)
}

for (j <- 0 +: i) {
  println(j)
}
```

Comment: Throwing a guess out there: could it be that overriding iterator as def means that it recomputes the new iterator everytime, thus always adding new iterator of the form 0,1,2,3 but taking always from 0?

Comment: On a stylistic note: you don't need to introduce a `val` for `outer`, the explicit reference to the outer object can also (and arguably more elegantly) be achieved by replacing the `val outer` line with `outer =>`.

Comment: Thank you, @misberner! I was hoping someone would comment on how to do that properly. I found [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/explicitly-typed-self-references.html) Scala Documentation article that introduces the `outer =>` syntactic construct, though for different purposes. Maybe there is a better reference?

Comment: In fact, @misberner, changing `val outer :Iterable[A] = this` to `outer =>` is not just stylistic. I found that it is necessary, and, combined with @Imm's fix, sufficient to produce the desired behavior. I wonder why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error in my original code is that `outer.iterator` returns a new iterator each time it's evaluated, as pointed out by @DiegoMartinoia and @Imm.

However, it is also necessary to replace `val outer = this` with `outer =>`, as suggested by @misberner.

*For now, this is only a partial answer to my question, as it doesn't explain why the second change is necessary.*

The corrected trait code is thus:

```scala
trait Iterable2[A] extends Iterable[A] {
  outer :Iterable[A] =>
  def +:(elem :A) = new Iterable2[A] {
    override def iterator: Iterator[A] = new Iterator[A] {
      private[this] var virgin = true
      private[this] val underlyingIterator = outer.iterator
      override def hasNext: Boolean = virgin || underlyingIterator.hasNext
      override def next(): A = {
        if (virgin) {virgin = false; elem}
        else underlyingIterator.next()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`outer.iterator` will always give you a new iterator. You need to create one and stash it somewhere, then use that single stashed one rather than creating a new one every time:

```
new Iterator[A] {
  val outerIterator = outer.iterator
  override def hasNext = ...
}
```

Comment: True, I didn't think of that. However, this is not enough to produce the desired behavior. It needs to be combined with @misberner's suggestion.